# Drawing circle and keeping the first uploaded sprite

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So first, I uploaded a car to the canvas and gave it turning and motion properties. I tried to draw a circle to go alongside the car but it is not working properly. The circle is alone and flickering for some reason. I removed the timeout completely, and both the circle and car disappeared. Adjusting the timeout rate doesn't remove the flicker. Help me get them on the screen and keep them there together please?
http://jsbin.com/zogeraduze/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your car image, but it seems like you have a setInterval set to 30ms and you call a timeout every 10ms (which is equivalent to a setInterval), each time clearing the canvas, hence creating a flickering. You should have only one repaint function that should clear the canvas, draw the car and then draw the circle.

try

```
//Setting the canvas and context
var canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
//Uploading car
var car = new Image();
car.src = "file:///H:/Desktop/Game/img/car.png";

//Setting properties of car
var x = 450;
var y = 730;
var speed = 10;
var angle = 990;
var mod = 0;

//Event listeners for keys
window.addEventListener("keydown", keypress_handler, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", keyup_handler, false);

//Drawing the car turning and changing speed
function draw() {

    x += (speed * mod) * Math.cos(Math.PI / 180 * angle);
    y += (speed * mod) * Math.sin(Math.PI / 180 * angle);

    context.save();
    context.translate(x, y);
    context.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * angle);
    context.drawImage(car, -(car.width / 2), -(car.height / 2));
    context.restore();
}

//Setting the keys
function keyup_handler(event) {
    console.log('a');
    if (event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 40) {

        mod = 0;
    }
}

//Setting all of the keys
function keypress_handler(event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
    if (event.keyCode == 38) {
        mod = 1;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 40) {
        mod = -1;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        angle -= 5;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        angle += 5;
    }
}


var context = $('#gameCanvas')[0].getContext('2d');
var width = $('#gameCanvas').width();
var height = $('#gameCanvas').height();

var circleX = width / 2;
var circleY = height / 2;
var circleVX = 1.0;
var circleVY = 0.0;
var circleR = 30;

function update() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);


/*
  circleX = Math.random() * (width - 2 * circleR) + circleR;
  circleY = Math.random() * (height - 2 * circleR) + circleR;
*/
  draw();
  drawCircle(circleX, circleY, circleR);

  setTimeout(update, 10);
}

function canvasClick(event) {
  var clickX = event.pageX;
  var clickY = event.pageY;
  var edgeX = clickX - circleX;
  var edgeY = clickY - circleY;
  var r = Math.sqrt(edgeX * edgeX + edgeY * edgeY);
  if (r < circleR) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  }
}

function drawCircle(x, y, r) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.fill();

  context.lineWidth = 3;
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';
  context.stroke();
}

$('#gameCanvas').click(canvasClick);
update();
```

Also, look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame instead of using timeouts